# Tools for building scheduling software

Tags: frameworks, web, scheduling

I am freelance programmer and i have a client who wants to build web-based software for scheduling/booking events. There is very few rules for possible booking options, but they are somewhat uncommon so there is no ready-made software to fully support them.

Anyway, besides that, the most important part is pretty common: calendar with events, reminders etc. So i believe there is some tools i can use, at least for that part.

What i'm interested in, is what tools can i use to build custom calendar, where i can write my own rules to prohibit user from booking in certain situations? Maybe there is some special framework (or, much more likely, plugins for web-frameworks) for scheduling software? If not, which ready-made software support maximum customization?

Answer (score 0):

Well since you didn't specify what language your most familiar with i'll just stick to php.

Now you have a few options here.

**A)** You can start from a framework with some libraries and build from there. The major pro is that you can customize it like you want it. Downside would be more time actually making it, and since a client sets specific deadlines this might not be the right solutions.

**B)** You could start with something like Joomla. Now I do agree that it does have it's bloat, more than a million lines of code if I can remember. But with some searching I found some good booking systems that are built into modules.

If you go with B, you will be able to worry on details instead of the core grunt stuff. I've used joomla for a few different sites, and it's extremely customizable if you spend time with it.

In the end it's honestly related to your time restrictions, and your language of choice. Joomla is built with PHP if your wondering.

Hope this helps,
Daniel